# Change React Native expo API level target

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to release my App on GooglePlay but I get this error message , Apparently my Expo App is  targeting Api level 30 , and I need to change it to target Api level 31.

I tried installing BuildProperties by doing an  `expo install expo-build-properties`

and trying to set target sdk version in the plugins but didnt work

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M9os.png)

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "klearners",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^3.0.9",
    "react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^2.2.11",
    "react-native-react-native-quiz-single-choice": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-tts": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.0",
    "react-translate-json": "^2.1.0",
    "react-youtube": "^9.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AppName",
    "slug": "AppName",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/logo.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#5e9bff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-3*******************"
      },
      "package": "com.name.AppName"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "ca****-****-****-****-**************"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
      "expo-build-properties",
      {
        "android": {
          "compileSdkVersion": 31,
          "targetSdkVersion": 31,
          "buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
        },
        "ios": {
          "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
        }
      }
    ]
    ]
  }
}
```

**eas.json**

```
{
    "build": {
      "preview": {
        "android": {
        }
      },
      "preview2": {
        "android": {
          "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
        }
      },
      "preview3": {
        "developmentClient": true
      },
      "production": {}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use expo-upgrade in your project delete node_modules and run yarn or npm install again

```
expo-upgrade
//Delete node_modules
yarn //Or npm i
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).